# Como traduz essa fórmula do excel inglês para o português?

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

A fórmula é essa:

```
= IF (E2 = 1, SLOPE (OFFSET (E2,0, -1, ninbox, 1), OFFSET (E2,0, -4, ninbox, 1)), ””)
```

Eu estou usando o seguinte, que não está funcionando:

```
= SE(E2 = 1; INCLINAÇÃO (DESLOC(E2;0;-1; ninbox; 1);DESLOC (E2;0; -4; ninbox; 1));””)
```

Eu sei que os argumentos da função SE, é da forma:

= SE(teste_lógico; [valor_se_verdadeiro];[valor_se_falso])

Função DESLOC:

DESLOC(C2;1;2;3;1)

Função INCLINAÇÃO:

INCLINAÇÃO(val_conhecidos_y; val_conhecidos_x)

Mas não entendi direito a função de ;”” na fórmula.

Comment: E o que vem a ser `nimbox`? A função `deslocamento`espera receber a **altura** nesta posição. Talvez a planilha original tenha uma célula nomeada com este nome. Pelo que me lembro o Excel aceita as funções com o nome em inglês.

Comment: É apenas uma coluna nomeada dessa forma, amigo.

Comment: Não sei se foi apenas um problema de transcrição para o SOpt mas este ˮˮ final deveria ser "". Isso que você não entendeu é uma string vazia que será exibida caso E1 seja diferente de 1.

Comment: O que você chama de "não estar funcionando"? Qual é o erro?

Comment: Aparece a mensagem padrão de "Encontramos problema na fórmula"

Comment: O `;""` é a parte falsa do `SE`. Basicamente voce tem algo como `SE(E2 = 1; INCLINAÇÃO(...) ; "")`. Ou seja se a célula E2 tiver o valor 1 você mete a inclinação, caso contrário deixa a célula vazia. E já agora, atenção às aspas que é suposto serem aspas normais e não essas aspas do word.

Comment: Era as aspas mesmo, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja ocorrendo erro devido ao **aspas**, em que tem que ser nesse formato: **""**

Eu fiz aqui e funcionou, apenas troquei as **aspas** e o **ninbox** por **2**:

```
=SE(E2=1;INCLINAÇÃO(DESLOC(E2;0;-1;2;1);DESLOC(E2;0;-4;2;1));"")
```

Exemplo com **ninbox**:

```
=SE(E2=1;INCLINAÇÃO(DESLOC(E2;0;-1;ninbox;1);DESLOC(E2;0;-4;ninbox;1));"")
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui também! Valeu!